# How do $scope and this techniques differ in terms of sharing data via services?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**If you're going to create new code, please don't change the original jsbins**

I am writing an app in angular 1. Right now I need to create a service I can inject in multiple controllers. I also need the data to be changeable in the various controllers but reflect the changes across the controllers. So I guess what I want are global values that have 2 way binding. I have been using a "var vm = this" technique instead of using $scope. I've read that they are essentially the same aside from syntax. But I have two examples with the same goal in mind creating different results.

They both share this service:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var stringValue = 'test string value';
    var objectValue = {
        data: 'test object value'
    };

    return {
        getString: function() {
            return stringValue;
        },
        setString: function(value) {
            stringValue = value;
        },
        getObject: function() {
            return objectValue;
        }
    }
});
```

I have set up two jsbin's to display their functionality.

Here's the "this" example:
http://jsbin.com/conidesuni/edit?html,js,output

Here's the $scope example:
http://jsbin.com/gobodutaje/edit?html,js,output

There are two sources of inputs, one binded to the objectValue and another binded to both the objectValue and stringValue. In the input that sets both values, the service's set function is called.

The difference is that $scope seems to bind across the two binded divs in controller two, but the "this" example isn't doing that. The this example is not changing any values when attempting to change both values at the same time (stringValue and objectValue). It prints undefined in the console.

Neither techniques cause the input in controller2 to change the divs in controller1 despite them sharing a service.

**I want to know how I can make these binds two ways across the controllers and what exactly is the difference between what is happening with the "this" example and $scope example.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `$scope` and `this` are the same thing as you stated at your question.

When you retrieve `ControllerAs`(`myController2 as cont2`) in your template, everything(variables and functions) you want to access from template to controller must have a prefix of `cont2`.

And in your first [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/conidesuni/edit?html,js,output), you have missed one prefix `cont2` at calling `cont2.setString(newValue)` and it should be `cont2.setString(cont2.newValue)`. else you can't pass what you have typed at the textbox.

---

**UPD:**

Normally if value lept at sharedService changed, we have to manually call service functions to get the newValue as answered by @Sumit Deshpande.

There is still another way that you can bind the **same object instance** to controller's varaible with the object instance kept in sharedService, but keep in mind that this way don't support filed of string type(unless you put the string filed in object filed too).

refer the below **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K4sthIX9E5oVAH0Ot0nI?p=preview)**.

Comment: You've got a sharp eye. I didn't realize the values I passed have to be preconfigured with the controller's "as" syntax.

Comment: It still doesn't change the the "test string value" in controller 2 the way that scope does.

Comment: @munchschair sorry for late response. check `UPD` part to see whether it helps or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

To reflect the data when change is happened in service there are 2 ways to do that -

1. Use Publisher Subscriber mechanism to broadcast and listen when change occurred in service variable/object.
2. Bind directly through service method to achieve the same.

Here is the sample code for 2# -

```
app.controller('myController1', function($timeout, sharedProperties) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.service = sharedProperties;
});

app.controller('myController2', function(sharedProperties) {        
    var vm = this;
    vm.service = sharedProperties;  
    vm.setString = function(newValue) 
    {   console.log(newValue);
        vm.objectValue.data = newValue;
        vm.service.setString(newValue);
    };
});
```

Html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController1 as cont1">
      <ul>
        <li><b>myController1</b> (values won't change)</li>
        <li>{{cont1.service.getString()}}</li>
        <li>{{cont1.service.getObject()}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
    <div ng-controller="myController2 as cont2">
      <ul>
        <li><b>myController2</b> (values will change when Set Values is clicked or when 2-way binding textbox is modified)</li>
        <li>{{cont2.service.getString()}}</li>
        <li>{{cont2.service.getObject().data}}</li>
      </ul>
      <input type="text" ng-model="cont2.newValue"></input>
    <button ng-click="cont2.setString(cont2.newValue)">Set Values</button><br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="cont2.objectValue.data"></input>2-way binding to objectValue
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What if I want to call the variable directly? For example: objectValue.data; instead of using a getter or setter?

Comment: To do that you should use publisher subscriber service where on data change service will broadcast and controllers are going subscribe to listen the change. Check http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/