# Angularjs directive's template updates, but link does not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a **directive** with 2 way data binding scope, as following:

```
app.directive('channelStar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: 'This works fine : {{count}}',
    scope: {
      count: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // count is showing in template, but doesn't get updated here
      // actually it logs old scopes value
      console.log(scope.count);
    }
  }
});
```

In **Template** in my routing (using `ui-router` and nested states) :

```
<channel-star count="selectedChannel[0].channel_dir_members"></channel-star>
```

**Controller:**

```
httpService.request(...).then(function(result){
    $scope.selectedChannel = result.data;
    $rootScope.selectedChannel = result.data;
    // $scope.$applyAsync();
    // $rootScope.$applyAsync();
})
```

Any idea?

Comment: try to replace link with controller

Comment: did you tried a watcher on count to see what happen ? scope.$watch('count', function(newValue, oldValue) {});

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO Thanks. Watcher solved the problem, but I have some more directives. Having a lot of watcher doesn't seem a nice way.

Comment: @Fribu That doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link` function only run once, if you want to deal with its new value, you can use `scope.$watch` to watch `count`.

```
scope.$watch('count', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(newValue){
     //do something
  }
}, true);     // here parameter true is for deep compare objects, no need to use it when just for string
```

Comment: use ' if(newValue){...} ', to check on new value not every time.

Comment: @Maher feel free to modify my answer after you have confirmed.  I just had a bad time answering this question on my cellphone. :P

Comment: ow, ok my friend.

Comment: Thanks. Now works fine. But I haven't seen in any directives using `$watch`. Is it a good practice?

Comment: @vahidnajafi no problem, but avoid using $watch to much.

Comment: @Pengyy Thanks. This is what I wanted to say. I have a lot of directives. So I must use `$watch` in anywhere.

Comment: @vahidnajafi one way would be using shared service, but I didn't used it myself.  you may do some research or post another question to ask experts for it.

Comment: @vahidnajafi here is an example for sharedService  but not using directive since they are almost the same. hope it will help for something. :) 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093678/how-do-scope-and-this-techniques-differ-in-terms-of-sharing-data-via-services/44093977#44093977

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below code in your directive.
scope.$apply(function() {});

see below link to for further information:
https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/scope-vs-scope

Comment: Would you please explain more?? I'm changing `$scope` in controller , not in the directive.

Comment: can you provide any fiddle, so that i can look into it. generally what happen is when you define scope inside your directive, what angular does is, to create new scope object instead of assign value to to your  previous one. That's why you are not getting your value in controller.